# Problems with CUPS

Tags: printing, 19.10

I hope that I am asking in the right place.

I am using Ubuntu 19.10. I downloaded and installed the latest version of CUPS 2.3.1. I am following the instructions from Zebra printers documents. They provided a pdf.

When I get to the step "sudo /usr/sbin/cupsd", I get an error message that says "/usr/sbin/cupsd: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: _cupsMessageSave".

I think CUPS 2.2.12 is already on this Ubuntu. If I try to open that it worked but now nothing from that either.

Please help. I need my Zebra printer to work. I am ready to throw things in frustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### cups version

You should have `cups-daemon` version 2.2.12.

That's the version for Ubuntu 19.01.

```bsh
$ apt policy cups-daemon
cups-daemon:
  Installed: 2.2.12-2ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.2.12-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.12-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

#### Library problem

You have duplicated libraries on your system. You have mixed libraries. When you run `/usr/sbin/cupsd` the executable is trying to use libraries that were not build for this executable.

Check out which libraries `cupsd` depends on, by running:

```bsh
$ ldd /usr/sbin/cupsd
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff2fbde000)
    libpam.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0 (0x00007fb2c090f000)
    libpaper.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpaper.so.1 (0x00007fb2c0909000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007fb2c08ba000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007fb2c0812000)
    libavahi-common.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-common.so.3 (0x00007fb2c0804000)
    libavahi-client.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-client.so.3 (0x00007fb2c07f1000)
    libcups.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.so.2 (0x00007fb2c075e000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007fb2c0711000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb2c06ee000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb2c04fd000)
    libaudit.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1 (0x00007fb2c04d1000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb2c04cb000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fb2c04be000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fb2c0497000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007fb2c0477000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007fb2c0359000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb2c09c9000)
    libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007fb2c019a000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fb2c017e000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb2c002d000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007fb2bff50000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007fb2bff1f000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007fb2bff18000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007fb2bff09000)
    libcap-ng.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap-ng.so.0 (0x00007fb2bff01000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007fb2bfedc000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007fb2bfda7000)
    libidn2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007fb2bfd86000)
    libunistring.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007fb2bfc04000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007fb2bfbee000)
    libnettle.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6 (0x00007fb2bfbb6000)
    libhogweed.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4 (0x00007fb2bfb7c000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007fb2bfafb000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007fb2bfaf4000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fb2bfad9000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fb2bfacf000)
```

Check (or share) the output of your `ldd /usr/sbin/cupsd`. Maybe you have the same library name on `/usr/local/lib` and this last one is being used, instead of the default one from `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.

I think the key to your problem is in the `ldd /usr/sbin/cupsd` output.

Comment: I had to post it as an answer. This comment thing said it was to long to add to the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Can I delete the CUPS 2.3.1 Version? Will that make thing worse? I ran the code. I am not sure what it all means. I hope you can help. This was my output:

```
sudo ldd /usr/sbin/cupsd
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdc6bba000)
            libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f26f5fef000)
            libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f26f5fb5000)
            libcups.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.so.2 (0x00007f26f5f24000)
            libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f26f5d33000)
            /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f26f608c000)
            libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f26f5ce6000)
            libgnutls.so.30 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f26f5b27000)
            libavahi-common.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-common.so.3 (0x00007f26f5b17000)
            libavahi-client.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-client.so.3 (0x00007f26f5b04000)
            libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f26f5ae8000)
            libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f26f5999000)
            libkrb5.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f26f58bc000)
            libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f26f588b000)
            libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f26f5882000)
            libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f26f5873000)
            libp11-kit.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f26f573e000)
            libidn2.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007f26f571d000)
            libunistring.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007f26f559b000)
            libtasn1.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f26f5585000)
            libnettle.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6 (0x00007f26f554b000)
            libhogweed.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4 (0x00007f26f5513000)
            libgmp.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f26f5492000)
            libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f26f5443000)
            libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f26f543d000)
            libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f26f5436000)
            libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f26f5419000)
            libffi.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f26f540f000)
            libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f26f5367000)
            librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f26f535c000)
            liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f26f5335000)
            liblz4.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f26f5313000)
            libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f26f51f5000)
            libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f26f51d2000)
```

Comment: Yes, you can remove the existing `cups` version with `sudo apt remove --purge cups`, then `sudo apt --purge autoremove`. After the removal, install cups again, with: `sudo apt install cups`.